# SSLs and Port 443

Tags: port-forwarding, webserver, port, iis

I currently have a website on IIS running on Server 2019. When I put the HTTPS port as 443 the website works. But if I try to put it on a different port it gives an error. Is there anyway to allow the website to use a different port for the HTTPs connection.

Answer (score 2):

If your website is on a port other than the well-known port 443, the users will have to specify the port in the URL.

For example:

> https://contoso.com/whatever/document.txt

will tell your browser to use default port 443.

If you had the webserver running on 14443 instead, you'd have to use this URL.

> https://contoso.com:14443/whatever/document.txt

You can't force a change of port through DNS or anything like that.  A different URL has to be used.